# Is it safe to turn INNODB engine on when all the tables are MYISAM at the moment?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I need to have possibility to make transactions while using one of my mySQL tables. 
I could do that if I'd switch engine from MYISAM (which is set by default to all of the tables at the moment) to INNODB. 
However I am not MySQL server admin and guy who is has asked me if I have read about possible dangers of doing so.
I tried to find an answer and failed, so here's my question:

INNODB is currently DISABLED (it says so when im execute SHOW ENGINES). Can I turn it ON without risk of damaging any data in existing MYISAM tables? Are there any specific dangers when doing so?
MYSQL version of server is 5.09.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no danger to making another engine available for database and object creation in MySQL. You will have to stop and restart your MySQL service for it to take effect, so you'll have a modicum of downtime, so do it after business hours.